# At what speed does information move through the atoms of a rigid object?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, acoustics, refraction, continuum-mechanics

How fast does information travel on particles? I thought if you move a iron bar from one end it would take the speed of sound to move its other end. For example, theoretically if you hold an iron bar that has the length from the earth to the moon it would take 18 hours to move the other end. However on this [video](https://youtu.be/Vitf8YaVXhc?si=Ur9u_QD-RyfDatKN) at 3:00 it’s said that the mechanical clock arm atoms transfer the movement information at the speed of light? What's the difference?

Answer (score 34):

A mechanical impulse will travel along an iron bar at the speed of sound (which will depend on the material and also possibly on the frequency and amplitude of the impulse). But in the video the narrator is talking about a photon travelling along the length of the iron bar, and he is assuming that the photon travels at the speed of light in vacuum - which, of course, is unrealistic if the photon is *inside* the iron bar. Basically, you are finding inconsistencies in a not-very-good YouTube video.

Comment: Considering that this is the highest-voted answer at the moment, it might be sensible to add that the speed of sound depends on the material - probably very obvious to most people, but still. Also, I find it kind of a roundabout way to talk about this in terms of "sound"; the deciding factor is the "speed of pressure waves" in the material at hand, which of course equates to sound if/when it's a gas or liquid and ears are involved. ;)

Comment: @AnoE Thanks for the suggestion - I have edited my answer.

Comment: @AnoE I can still recall being surprised at the speed of sound in a material showing up in calculations of heat transport by phonons.  It's certainly counterintuitive

Comment: I'd add that a photon traveling with the speed of light along the length of the iron bar is true, assuming you mean the speed of light in iron. Which is not the speed in vacuum.

Comment: @BurnNote But what would be the relation between the photon travelling in the iron bar with movement as shown in the video. I think it is clear that the information travels at the speed of pressure waves but this would not be a photon. I just don’t understand why the person on the video talks about the photon moving between the atoms.

Comment: @JFrank I would bet that the error comes from the fact that the internal forces in solids are electromagnetic in nature: It is indeed electrons that communicate the change in relative movement between the atoms of the iron bar. But that doesn't mean that the acceleration imposed is transferred at this speed.

Comment: All this talk of photons *inside* iron bars got me to thinking that the speed of light in an iron bar is dependent on the index of refraction which is itself based on the wavelength of the photon in question, and which presumably can only be determined empirically, and furthermore this only applies to wavelengths that the iron bar is not opaque to...

Comment: Is "moving" a rod really the same as "banging" it? Same difference as applying pressure to a hydraulic fluid vs. having it conduct (sound) waves. It's not immediately clear to me that the two are the same.

Comment: And depend on temperature (higher speed at lower temperatures).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica It kind of is. Mathematically, it's the constant term, the zero frequency in a fourier transformation. Imagine waves with longer and longer periods. Eventually you reach a period of "infinity" and it's just constant. The same way you can have DC and AC at the same time, and the correspondence there is pretty direct.

Answer (score 14):

The question in the title is formally contradictory. A model is always a simplification of the real world for the sake of understanding and making predicions (usually mathematically) A "rigid object" is a mathematical model of an object that simplifies away things like atoms, so "atoms of a rigid object" is an oxymoron.

Rigid bodies are a useful model for Newtonian mechanics, but they don't work for Special Relativity. In relativity, a signal can't travel faster than the speed of light, so it might be useful to model a "maximally rigid" body, in which the motion is transmitted at this speed.  The transmission of movement from the centre of a clock to its tips is limited by the speed of light.

For actual practical clocks, the really transfer of motion happens much much slower, at the speed of sound in the substance. But this is a mass matter property. It is something that only appears when there are billions of atoms and their movements can be coordinated, not a fundamental fact about the universe.

Though I do wonder if thinking about time dilation (the least intuitive part of SR) is a good way gain intuition about the speed of light (something that seems more plausible)

Comment: So if the transmission of movement on the arms of a mechanical clock still happens at speed of sound, why the guy in the video says it’s at speed of light?

Comment: He is using a model of a message being passed along a single line of atoms.  He isn't really talking about a physical bar of iron.  It's a rather odd video...  To get intuition on the speed of light from time dilation seems the wrong way round.  Time dilation would seem to be the highly counter intuitive concept.